# What does "Fiscal State" mean?

Tags: word-usage

> **The fiscal state: Paying taxes in Switzerland**
>
> Every year, each household gets a tax form from the cantonal or local tax office. The
> responsible persons in the household are required to declare the
> salary earned last year and their fortune by the end of it. On the
> basis of their own declarations and after control by the authority,
> taxpayers get their bill. The commune or canton not only collects its
> own taxes but is mandated to also collect those of the other two
> levels. This demands much trust in the taxpayer and the collecting
> authority but is considered to be efficient for all parties involved.
>
> *Swiss Democracy by Linder Mueller*

What does fiscal state means in the heading? Does it mean "circumstances" or "nation"?
I have found some examples of the word "fiscal state" in the internet but they are ambiguous too.
Can please someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term “fiscal state” means  a state which is connected with government or public money (e.g. Taxes).

the term “State” refers to a nation or territory  considered as an organised political community under one government. So a non fiscal state would imply a state which is ran on the funds of the government alone e.g. no taxes.

So here “fiscal” relates to government revenue especially taxes.